# System.Net.Mail SmtpClient c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, system.net.mail

Does System.Net.Mail SmtpClient support smtp server with httpS or it work only with smtp servers with http?

I mean if i pass "https//:mysmtpserver" to constructor od SmtpClient instance - it would work?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SmtpClient` works with SSL, yes. You need to provide it as a property like this:

```cs
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
{
    Port = 587,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"),
    EnableSsl = true,
};
    
smtpClient.Send("email", "recipient", "subject", "body");
```

(taken from this article [How to send emails from C#/.NET - The definitive tutorial](https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/#using-smtp))

Comment: Does https require SSL? Is the port "587" required?

Comment: Not sure I understand the first part. HTTPS is HTTP over SSL, yes. Port 587 is the default port for SMTP over SSL (well TLS), but that depends on how the SMTP is configured, of course.

Comment: SmtpClient doesn't support Gmail port 465 iirc. That's a legacy SSL protocol. They support TLS or basic. 587 is the TLS port as indicated by @thomasardal and is the best option.